# How to copy all values in first row of selection to new sheet with vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy all values 14-22 (first row values of selection) to a new sheet in vba/Excel. How can I do this?

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "vacation-results"
Set vacationSheet = Sheets("vacation-results")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really necessary to use selection, try this:

```
' Copy the first row of values (not the header)
Selection.Rows.Item(2).Copy 

' Paste our clipboard content into the newly formed sheet
vacationSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solved my problem! Btw, "Item(2)" should be "Item(1)"

Comment: No problem. I only used `Item(2)` because I thought you wanted the first row of values, not the headers :)